# How to Print response in csv file using PHP

Tags: php, csv, multidimensional-array, response, extract

I have response array in variable  $listing array .Here is $listing Value:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => stdClass Object
     (
        [status] => failure
        [response] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ProId] => 1
                       [status] => failure
                        [errors] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [errorCode] => CONTENT_NOT_FOUND
                                        [message] => Content not found.
                                        [attributeName] => 
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ProId] => 2
                        [status] => failure
                        [errors] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [errorCode] => CONTENT_NOT_FOUND
                                        [message] => Content not found.
                                        [attributeName] => 
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ProId] => 3
                       [status] => updated
                        [errors] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ProId] => 4
                        [status] => updated
                        [errors] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [4] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ProId] => 5
                        [status] => updated
                        [errors] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [5] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ProId] => 6
                        [status] => updated
                        [errors] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [6] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ProId] => 7
                        [status] => updated
                        [errors] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [7] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ProId] => 8
                       [status] => updated
                        [errors] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [8] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ProId] => 9
                        [status] => updated
                        [errors] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )
                [9] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ProId] => 10
                        [status] => updated
                        [errors] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [status] => failure
        [response] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ProId] => 11
                        [status] => failure
                        [errors] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [errorCode] => CONTENT_NOT_FOUND
                                        [message] => Content not found.
                                        [attributeName] => 
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ProId] => 12
                        [status] => failure
                        [errors] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [errorCode] => CONTENT_NOT_FOUND
                                        [message] => Content not found.
                                        [attributeName] => 
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ProId] => 13
                       [status] => failure
                        [errors] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [errorCode] => CONTENT_NOT_FOUND
                                        [message] => Content not found.
                                        [attributeName] => 
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ProId] => 14
                        [status] => updated
                        [errors] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [4] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ProId] => 15
                        [status] => updated
                        [errors] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [5] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ProId] => 16
                       [status] => updated
                        [errors] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [6] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ProId] => 17
                        [status] => updated
                        [errors] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [7] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ProId] => 18
                        [status] => updated
                        [errors] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [8] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ProId] => 19
                        [status] => updated
                        [errors] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [9] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ProId] => 20
                        [status] => updated
                        [errors] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

I want to create one csv file with above response in below format .Please see attached image

[image]

For achieving this result i am using this code:

```
$fp = fopen('output.csv',"w");
                    $rowcounts=0;
                    $resultResponse=$listing->response;
                        while($rowcounts<$inputfielscount) {
                            $result=$resultResponse[$rowcounts];
                            $resultProId=$result->ProId;
                            $resultStatus=$result->status;
                            $resultErrors=$result->errors;
                            $errorMsgArray=$resultErrors[0];
                            $ErrorsMessage=$errorMsgArray->message; 
                            $ErrorCode=$errorMsgArray->errorCode;

                                if($resultStatus=='failure'){
                                            $list = array ($resultProId,$resultStatus,$ErrorCode,$ErrorsMessage);
                                }else {
                                            $list = array ($resultProId,$resultStatus,"successfully");
                                }
                                fputcsv($fp,$list);
                                $rowcounts++;
                        }
```

$listing is an response array what i already mansioned at first.
I am not  getting the desired result in csv file.If anyone has solution please share.

Comment: Do you also need the --------| formatting in the output? Also please try to mention what are you getting currently and what is that you expect here.

Comment: In dont' want ----| this in output,This i used as value should come in  csv file like this.

Answer (score 0):

This I think will shove it into an flat multi-diamential array, not too much trouble to then get it into a csv.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {

    if(isset($array[$key]) && count($array[$key]) > 0) {

        foreach($array[$key] as $inner) {

            $error = $inner['errors'][0];

            $new_array[] = array($inner->ProId,$inner->status,$error->errorCode,$error->message);

        }

    } 

}
```

Comment: Sorry, realized it was objects. not array elements. I've updated my answer. If that doesn't work it's not my problem. Incase you don't know phrases like 'this is not my requirement' aren't helpful and come off as rude.

Comment: Sorry @richard for my words,I got solution And yes i got idea from your answer.I deleted my comment.Thanks once again.

Comment: It's ok, I thought it might be because this English isn't your first language, but just take care when communicating.